# ListView adapter and onClickListener

Tags: android, listview

How to set onClickListener for button for each element in ListView?
When I do something like this:

```
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.element, parent, false);
        }

        mButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mButton.setText("Clicked");
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

And when I press the button I get this errors:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4c
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:286)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4148)
            at the.vizimir.onezone.adapters.PostListViewAdapter$1.onClick(ListViewAdapter.java:119)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19858)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

UPDATE:
I don't get errors but after clicking Button text is chaning not in this element where I press, but in other.

```
public class PostListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post> {
    private List<Post> mPostList;
    private Context mContext;

    Button mPlusImageButton;
    TextView mTextTextView;


    public PostListViewAdapter(List<Post> postList, Context context){
        super(context, R.layout.post, postList);
        mPostList = postList;
        mContext = context;

    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post, parent, false);
        }
        mPlusImageButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plusImageButton);
        mTextTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTextView);

        String mText = mPostList.get(position).getText();
        mTextTextView.setText(mText);

        int a = position;
        mPlusImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPlusImageButton.setText("A");
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return mPostList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure this layout --> element has a button with this id --> button

Comment: are you sure we are looking at the correct adapter ? `PostListViewAdapter` ?

Comment: Yes, I change names to better understanding

Comment: Did you see the message:  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException ??

Comment: Yes, but when I comment line mButton.setText there is no errrors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try to use:

```
Button thisButton = (Button) v;
```

instead of using it straight, if you totally sure that problem is `onClick()`

So, i've found a time, and made simple example, which works : 
MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        items.add("1");
        items.add("2");
        items.add("3");
        TestAdapter adapter = new TestAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.title, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

TestAdapter.class(*i know i'm not using ViewHolder pattern and so on, i've just made a class base on your example*) :

```
public class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private List<String> items;
    private Context mContext;

    public TestAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> items) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }

            final Button mButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            TextView mTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

            mTitle.setText(items.get(position));

            mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mButton.setText("clicked");
                }

            });

            return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

}
```

[image]

**So i need all of your code to see what's happening**

**Edit :** *Ofcourse you get text on wrong Button, you need to create them in getView(like in my post), and not as field in your adapter class.*

Comment: If you mean to add this in OnClick and do something like that: thisButton.setText -> it doesn't work

Comment: so, you have same error? Then try other answer please

Comment: I added code above, but nothing happen when I click button, have I done it properly?

Comment: Think so, but this is a strange way to do it, maybe you should call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), but even if it will work, i suggest you to find another way

Comment: I can find you other way to do it, but i'm buy right now, maybe in a few hours, try it for now

Comment: Thanks, I hope you find time

Comment: I added final Button mButton in getView, but know text is changing in right way but in few other is also change, I don't know why.

Comment: Then you should see tutorials on __ViewHolder patter__ , this will help you to avoid this issue

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to use buttons.
For listviews use onListItemClick. Its a method built into ListFragment. Otherwise use listview.setOnItemClickListener(); hope that helps. They take parameters ListView l, View v, int position, long id

Comment: Element is more complicated so I have to use one from other buttons. But when I add ListView l, android studio says that one of the parameters is AdapterView

Answer (score 0):

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mButton.setText("clicked");
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```